# Convert a flexi-stream containing a vector of octets to a utf-8 string in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I use the following code to convert the content of a flexi-stream to an utf-8 string:

```
(babel:octets-to-string  (slot-value (getf request :raw-body) 'vector)
                                                 :encoding :utf-8)
```

Inspecting :raw-body in the request plist shows the following object.

```
#<FLEXI-STREAMS::VECTOR-INPUT-STREAM {7007F67D63}>
--------------------
Class: #<STANDARD-CLASS FLEXI-STREAMS::VECTOR-INPUT-STREAM>
--------------------
All Slots:
[ ]  END         = 169
[ ]  INDEX       = 0
[ ]  OPEN-P      = T
[ ]  TRANSFORMER = NIL
[ ]  VECTOR      = @6=#(112 114 111 99 101 115 115..)
```

It looks odd/wrong to me to extract the `vector` slot from the stream and convert it, instead of reading sequentially from the stream.

Am I doing it "wrong"? If yes why?
How does one access streams idiomatically in Common Lisp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with using the slot value like this is that it doesn't consume the contents of the input stream.

[Flexi-streams and friends](https://edicl.github.io/flexi-streams/) aren't standard Common Lisp, but you can use `read-byte` and `read-sequence` with them.

The simplest solution is probably to use a library function like `read-stream-content-into-byte-vector` from Alexandria:

```lisp
CL-USER> (babel:octets-to-string
          (alexandria:read-stream-content-into-byte-vector (getf request :raw-body)))
```

You could write your own function to get a string from a stream using [`read-byte`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_by.htm). Here is a simple function that just reads a byte at a time from the input stream and shoves it into a vector until there are no more bytes to read. This is not written for performance, but rather to get the thing done:

```lisp
(defun stream->string (stream &key (initial-size 1024))
  (do ((buffer (make-array initial-size
                           :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)
                           :adjustable t
                           :fill-pointer 0))
       (b (read-byte stream nil)))
      ((null b) (return (babel:octets-to-string buffer)))
    (vector-push-extend b buffer)
    (setf b (read-byte stream nil))))
```

A better and somewhat more involved solution could use [`read-sequence`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_seq.htm) to read larger blocks of bytes at a time. Here is one way to write that; I would expect this to have better performance than the version above that uses `read-byte`, but I haven't tested that:

```lisp
(defun stream->string (stream &key (initial-size 1024))
  (do* ((buffer (make-array initial-size
                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)
                            :adjustable t
                            :fill-pointer t))
        (buffer-size initial-size)
        (next (read-sequence buffer stream)))
       ((< next buffer-size)
        (setf (fill-pointer buffer) next)
        (return (babel:octets-to-string buffer)))
    (setf buffer-size (* 2 buffer-size))
    (adjust-array buffer buffer-size :fill-pointer t)
    (setf next (read-sequence buffer stream :start next))))
```

This last version reads bytes into an array using `read-sequence`. If the array is filled during this operation it is resized by doubling its capacity. `next` keeps track of the next position to be written to in the array. When this value is smaller than the current `buffer-size` the contents of the stream were written into the `buffer` array without filling it, so the stream has been exhausted. The fill pointer is then set to the end of the buffer contents before passing the buffer to `babel:octets-to-string`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're doing it wrong.  In particular you *certainly* do not want to be poking around in the internal implementation of things the way you are doing.  Instead use the [documented interface to FLEXI-STREAMS](https://edicl.github.io/flexi-streams/).

The stream you are trying to read is, in fact, not a `flexi-stream`: it's an `in-memory-stream`.  These are provided by the FLEXI-STREAMS system but they're not actually flexible: they just wrap sequences of octets, and you can't read characters from them at all.  This is one of the reasons your approach is unsafe: `in-memory-stream`s can have transformer functions which rewrite their data on the way in or out, which your code simply ignores.

So, there are a couple of approaches to doing this, both just using FLEXI-STREAMS' own facilities.

- you could write a function which, using `read-sequence`, grabs a vector of octets from the stream, and then use `octets-to-string` on that;
- of you could just wrap the stream in a `flexi-stream` and grab a string from that, relying on the stream to do the work for you.

The details of how you might do this depend on how much you care about things like performance.  Here's one version of the second approach which, at least in theory, makes some attempt to allow you to do things like reuse buffers, and reads big chunks from the stream at a time rather than character by character.  This makes use of [Tim Bradshaw's `iterate`](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#applicative-iteration-iterate) applicative iteration macro: you could rewrite it using something else if you wanted to.

First of all here's a little function which will return a flexi stream for a stream (if the stream is not itself a flexi stream it should be a binary stream).

```
(defgeneric flexi-stream-for (s &key &allow-other-keys)
  (:documentation "Return a flexi stream for a stream

If the stream is a flexi stream then it is returned unless keyword
arguments are given, when a flexi stream is wrapped around it.")
  (:method ((s flexi-stream) &rest keys &key)
   (if keys
       (call-next-method)
     s))
  (:method ((s stream) &rest keys &key)
   (apply #'make-flexi-stream s keys)))
```

Now here is a function which will read the contents, or some of the contents, of a flexi stream into an array.  This function is written with the assumption that you probably want to reuse the buffer: it's somewhat extravagant if you don't.  Note that the array it returns is generally longer than what it read: the second value tells you where it read to.

```
(defun flexi-stream-contents (stream &key
                                     (element-type 'character)
                                     (initial-length 1024)
                                     (resize-factor 2)
                                     (buffer (make-array initial-length
                                                         :element-type element-type))
                                     (start 0)
                                     (end nil))
  "Get the content of a flexi stream, or possibly some of it.

- s is the stream to read
- element-type is the element-type of the sequence to return
  (ignored if buffer given)
- initial-length is the initial length of the buffer to create
  (ignored if buffer given)
- resize-factor is the factor to resize the buffer by
- buffer, if given, is a buffer to reuse
- start, if given, is the start position in the buffer, default is 0
- end, if given, is how long the buffer is allowed to get.  Default is
  nil, meaning there's no limit to the buffer size
Returns the buffer, the end position in the buffer, and whether
or not we read the whole stream."
  ;; CAUTION: not heavily tested.
  (assert (> resize-factor 1) (resize-factor)
    "resize factor must be greater than 1")
  (iterate next ((b buffer)
                 (s start)
                 (l (length buffer)))
    (let ((p (read-sequence b stream :start s :end (if end (min l end) l))))
      (cond
       ((< p l)
        (cond
         ((not end)
          ;; end of file in the stream
          (values b p t))
         ((< p end)
          ;; same
          (values b p t))
         (t
          ;; may have hit end of file
          (values b p (if (peek-byte stream nil nil nil) nil t)))))
       ((peek-byte stream nil nil nil)
        ;; end of the buffer, but there is more in the stream
        (let* ((nl (if end
                       (min (ceiling (* l resize-factor)) end)
                     (ceiling (* l resize-factor))))
               (nb (adjust-array b nl)))
          (next nb p nl)))
       (t
        ;; end of the buffer, nothing in stream
        (values b p nil))))))
```

Now, if you have any kind of octet stream you can decode it to a string like this:

```
(defun octet-stream-string (s &key (external-format ':utf-8))
  (with-open-stream (w (flexi-stream-for s :external-format external-format))
    (multiple-value-bind (b p eof) (flexi-stream-contents w)
      (declare (ignore eof))
      (subseq b 0 p))))
```

Obviously in real life you'd want to be reusing the buffer!

Here's that in action

```
> (with-input-from-sequence (in #(207 132 207 129 206 177 
                                      207 133 206 187 206 
                                      175 206 182 207 137))
    (octet-stream-string in))
"τραυλίζω"
```

---

There are obviously other approaches to doing this, and in particular although this approach (in particular `flexi-stream-contents`) makes a lot of palaver about possibly being efficient, I have not actually measured it against some more naïve approach which would be a bunch simpler.

The important thing, though, is to use the documented interface.